# Regex for suffix detection in GoLang

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to enforce that a string I'm checking must end with a colon. However, I want to allow any set of characters prior to that.

The following are allowed:

```
match, _ := regexp.MatchString("([a-z]+):", "hello:") // Pass
match, _ := regexp.MatchString("([a-z]+):", "a12ab3c4:") // Pass
match, _ := regexp.MatchString("([a-z]+):", "a12#ab3c4:") // Pass
```

The following should fail:

```
match, _ := regexp.MatchString("([a-z]+):", ":::")  // Fail
match, _ := regexp.MatchString("([a-z]+):", "key1") // Fail
match, _ := regexp.MatchString("([a-z]+):", "")     // Fail
match, _ := regexp.MatchString("([a-z]+):", ":")    // Fail
match, _ := regexp.MatchString("([a-z]+):", "")     // Fail
```

I'm not quite sure how to come up with a regex expression to check for a trailing colon. `([a-z]+):` doesn't quite seem to work.

Comment: `[a-z]` won't match uppercase characters or numbers; use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` instead

Comment: Should `hello::` pass or fail?

Comment: Your *must end with a colon* is not a complete set of requirements judging by the examples. What are the exact requirements for the pattern? Any 1+ chars other than `:` and then `:` at the end? Try `regexp.MatchString(\`^[^:]+:$\`, s)`, but it won't match `hello::` as there are 2 `:`s.

Comment: @janos it should pass

Comment: Try [`^.*[a-z].*:$`](https://regex101.com/r/DPKqNt/1) if you need to make sure there is at least 1 lowercase letter and the `:` at the end.

Comment: A regular expression is probably not the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it, match any amount of characters (not ':') and end on ':'

```
^[^:]+:+$
```

Comment: This accepts no characters before colon, and `{1}` is redundant

Comment: @ctwheels I believe it does, you can test it here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: I know it doesn't, in fact, here's a regex101 link that proves it: https://regex101.com/r/0f23ht/2

Comment: uhh it works for the most part, but can you help me capture the case where it's just ":", that should fail. https://play.golang.org/p/19r8Vonl87

Comment: @Ramie `^[^:]+:$`

Comment: Neither will match `hello::`

Comment: Woops, misunderstood the "no characters before colon" for something like "abc:", you're right :)

Comment: Updated to support multiple ':' at the end ^[^:]+:+$

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a regular expression, but a much simpler, and better performing, way of accomplishing your goal would be something like:

```
func Matches(str string) bool {
    return str[len(str)-1] == ':' &&
        !strings.ContainsRune(str[0:len(str)-1], ':')
}
```